# Is it good to use vuex-persistedstate to get user information after refreshing the page?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex

I use nodeJS on the backend and Vue with Vuex on the frontend. I have the logic for logging the user and everything works great, I put the JWT token in the Cookie and from there I read it and decode and log the user. When I refresh the page, my data is lost, so I'm wondering if it's a good practice to use vuex-persistedstate and save the entire state after refreshing?

This is my Vuex Store:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import router from './router';

import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import './bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './App.vue';
import API from './API';

const store = createStore({
  state: {
    user: {},
    userLoading: null,
    userError: null,
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      storage: {
        getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
        setItem: (key, value) =>
          Cookies.set(key, value, { expires: 3, secure: true }),
        removeItem: key => Cookies.remove(key),
      },
    }),
  ],
  getters: {},
  mutations: {
    SET_USER(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload;
    },
    SET_USER_LOADING(state, payload) {
      state.userLoading = payload;
    },
    SET_USER_STATUS_FAIL(state, payload) {
      state.userError = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async login({ commit }, User) {
      commit('SET_USER_LOADING', true);
      commit('SET_USER', []);
      try {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        };

        const { data } = await API.post(`/api/v1/users/login`, User, config);
        commit('SET_USER', data);
        commit('SET_USER_LOADING', false);
      } catch (error) {
        commit('SET_USER_LOADING', false);

        commit(
          'SET_USER_STATUS_FAIL',
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message
        );
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Sure, that'll work. Just remember something key here: local storage calls are synchronous and thread blocking, the more you stuff in there the longer you're going to block page execution. as long as you remember that and can work with that, then you're fine.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy nice man, i was trying to do multiple things but.. i don't know, i know LocalStorage is not good practise to store user but i don't know other way, i am still a beginner in Vue and Vuex so i guess this is nice solution. If you have better solution how to improve you can send me some resources. Thank you

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing user information in local storage. I don't know where you got that impression but it's fine. Just make sure to clean up any data when their session expires / they logout.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy nice, now i am trying to find how to store just user (not whole state) and when logout to delete cookie and vuex cookie. Thank you for the answer